# How to fix Google Cloud Rails deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy a Rails app for testing using Google Cloud. I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) by Google.

When I run the `gcloud app deploy` command, I get the following error message after some time:

> Your bundle only supports platforms ["x64-mingw32"] but your local platforms are ["ruby", "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two
>   lists.

I have a feeling that I am missing something regarding my bundle's operating systems support, but I don't know where the issue is located.

Comment: Try to deploy without your gemfile.lock (it restricts the platform your app can run on)

Comment: @escanxr Are you saying I delete it?

Comment: You are able to skip some files with `skip_files` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files. I never used gcloud but it should to the trick. For the test you can just remove the `gemfile.lock`, gcloud will regenerate it on the server when it will execute the `bundle install`

Comment: It worked! But I face a different error now. Go ahead and post the answer. A little explanation would be nice, too.