# How to fix "bundler: command not found: rails" when deploying using Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my Rails app to Google Cloud using App Engine Flexible Environment. Everything works fine when I run `gcloud app deploy`, but at the very end, when App Engine tries to run my application using `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`, as specified in my `app.yaml` file, it crashes and gives the following error message:

> Error Response: [9] Application startup error: 'bundler: command not
>   found: rails Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

I tried changing the `entrypoint` value, running `bundle install` again and again, and installing all my gem files locally, but none of that worked. I also tried installing rack and changing the endpoint to run the app using `rackup` command, but that didn't work either. I am also skipping my `gemfile.lock` in my `app.yaml` file due to a previous error that was [solved on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312065/how-to-fix-google-cloud-rails-deployment-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error is because I was skipping the `Gemfile.lock` due to a previous error that I thought was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312065/how-to-fix-google-cloud-rails-deployment-issue). The aforementioned 'solution' led to this error. The solution that I found is to make some edits to `Gemfile.lock` that solved the issue instead of avoiding it. The edits can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312065/how-to-fix-google-cloud-rails-deployment-issue).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd also want to install bundler in your container instance.

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Still getting the same error... I edited my Q; maybe skipping `gemfile.lock` is causing this?